"@reboot" in root crontab, instead of systemctl scripts - clever solution or with many disadvantages?
I am maintaining a new application and they have no init scripts or systemctl scripts.
They use crontab with content like here:
# Start App2 at reboot
@reboot (. /home/app2/.bash_profile; /opt/app2/Groovy/setGroovyEnv.sh; cd /opt/app2/instance4/current; ./startScript.sh) >> /dev/null 2>&1

Important: the application does not have to be stopped gracefully.
Somehow this approach is simpler than writing a unit file.
Are there any important disadvantages that I don't see? When rebooting, the app always starts up cleanly.

Two disadvantages I see: 1) It's not easy to restart the app, should that be needed. Are users expected to copy that magic invocation from the crontab? 2) It's not easy to control execution, e.g., I can do systemctl disable app2.service if I don't want it started on reboot for a while and instead have it started manually, but here I need to edit a crontab and comment out a line. Also: 3) not much of a disadvantage, but if those redirections were removed, it would be much easier to see the messages in journalctl if the need arises. Whether any of that matters is a matter of opinion.

thanks @muru - please turn comment into an answer that I can upvote
